# How can I stack a dataset using stack function in D3

Tags: d3.js, stacked

I have this dataset:

```
 var dataset = [
    { "Date":"2014-10", "updates":427, "insert":27, "remove":29},
    { "Date":"2014-12", "updates":27, "insert":57, "remove":9},
    { "Date":"2015-02", "updates":47, "insert":7, "remove":2},
    { "Date":"2015-03", "updates":447, "insert":27, "remove":79}
    ];
```

I want to stack this dataset, using d3.layout.stack(dataset) function to create a stacked bar chart using D3, like this (http://bl.ocks.org/anupsavvy/9513382).
I'm having some problems because this function doesn't stack my data correctly by this three vectors: updates, insert, remove. The dataset stays exactly the same after the calling of stack(dataset) function an I cannot perform the correct integration with the example above.

I any form to transform the dataset or calling specific parameters to create this stacked dataset?

Thanks,
Filipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this work:

```
var output = ["updates", "insert", "remove"].map(
    function (v) {
    return dataSet.map(function (d) {
        return {
            Date : d.Date,
            y : +d[v]
        };
    });
});
```